# How to run piece of code within main script then update main script with results from above code

Tags: powershell

I have below codes which are part of big main script here i am generating code for display since dates are random so i can't write display format in advance. so using below piece of code to format display.

```
$dates = ("2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27")
    function display ($dates){
                $num = 1
                $beg = '"{0,-25}'
                $end = '" -f "Job_Name"'
                    ForEach ($dt in $dates){
                
                $ft += " {$num,10}"
                
                $dtt += ",""$dt"""
                $num ++
                                                }
                "$($beg) $($ft) $($end)$($dtt)"
                                    }
                
               display $dates
```

I am getting output like below when main script runs , i would like to run code within main script and update script with output.
"{0,-25}  {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27"
When main script runs display should be

Job_name 2022-07-29 2022-07-28 2022-07-27

Actually below is my main code where I have manually write dates in code to get output. But I would like this piece automated, any idea how can I do ?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][string]$vip,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][string]$username,
    [Parameter()][string]$domain = 'local',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][array]$jobNames, # job to run
    [Parameter()][int]$Days
)

### source the cohesity-api helper code
. ./cohesity-api

### authenticate
apiauth -vip $vip -username $username -domain $domain

$dayusec  = [int64](((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())-([datetime]"1970-01-01 00:00:00")).TotalSeconds*1000000

$TB = 1024*1024*1024*1024

$dateString = (get-date).ToString().Replace(' ','_').Replace('/','-').Replace(':','-')
$outfileName = "RunStats-$dateString.csv"
"JobName,Job start Time,Status,RunType,Duration in Min, ReadGBytes, writeGBytes" | Out-File -FilePath $outfileName

$endtime = $dayusec
$data = @{}
$jobs = api get protectionJobs?isDeleted=false
$dates =@()
            for ($day=1;$day -lt $days -or $day  -eq $days;$day ++){
                $dates += ((get-date).AddDays(-$day)).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                                                  }

foreach ($jobname in $jobNames){   ###1
       $endtime = $dayusec
       
        for ($day=1;$day -lt $days -or $day  -eq $days;$day ++){   ###2
               
               $starttime = [int64](((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())-([datetime]"1970-01-01 00:00:00")).TotalSeconds*1000000 - ($day * 86400000000)
                    if ($jobname -notin $data.keys){
                             $data[$jobname]=@{}
                                                }


                        foreach ($job in $jobs){     #  starts jobs loop
    
                                         if ( $jobname -eq $job.name){
                                           $jobId = $job.id
                                           #$starttime = $usec
                                           $runs = api get "protectionRuns?jobId=$($job.id)&startTimeUsecs=$starttime&endTimeUsecs=$endtime&runTypes=kRegular"
                                                                     }
                                               }

                            foreach ($run in $runs){
                                $nowTime = dateToUsecs (get-date)
                                $7thday = (dateToUsecs ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7)))
                                $startTime = $run.copyRun[0].runStartTimeUsecs
                                $date =  (usecsToDate $starttime).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd’)
                                        
                                     if ($run.backupRun.runType.substring(1) -eq "Regular"){   #  starts last day
            
                                    $readMBytes = [math]::Round($run.backupRun.stats.totalBytesReadFromSource / $TB, 3)
                                    $data[$jobname][$date]=$readMBytes
                                    
                                    #"$($jobName)     $($readMBytes) $($date)"
                                                                                             }
                 
                            }
                                        $endtime = $starttime
                                        
                                } ###2
                } ###1

                
                "{0,-25} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} {4,10} {5,10} {6,10} {7,10} {8,10} {9,10} {10,10} {11,10} {12,10} {13,10} {14,10}" -f "Job Name","2022-07-28","2022-07-27","2022-07-26","2022-07-25","2022-07-24","2022-07-23","2022-07-22","2022-07-21","2022-07-20","2022-07-19","2022-07-18","2022-07-17","2022-07-16","2022-07-15"
                
                "==============================================================================================================="
                $data.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object {
                "{0,-20} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} {4,10} {5,10} {6,10}  {7,10} {8,10} {9,10} {10,10} {11,10} {12,10} {13,10}  {14,10}" -f $_.name,$_.value."2022-07-28",$_.value."2022-07-27",$_.value."2022-07-26",$_.value."2022-07-25",$_.value."2022-07-24",$_.value."2022-07-23",$_.value."2022-07-22",$_.value."2022-07-21",$_.value."2022-07-20",$_.value."2022-07-19",$_.value."2022-07-18",$_.value."2022-07-17",$_.value."2022-07-16",$_.value."2022-07-15"

                                                 }
```

If you look above its very tedious to put date in advance to get desired output and also if i change value of $days from 14 to any other value, i have to update above code with dates again to get desired output. I would like display get adjusted as value of $days changes.

Comment: What do you mean with "*update script with output.*". Where should the output of `display`function go to? To the console?, a variable? Both?, a file? What works and what doesn't?  It is very  confusing what exactly you are trying to do. Can you show (a part) of your "*main script*"?

Answer (score 1):

Relative to what you have posted, the results are not what you are showing.

**(unless you are doing formatting elsewhere in your script which you are not showing)**

```
Clear-Host
$dates = ("2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27")

function display ($dates)
{
    $num = 1
    $beg = '"{0,-25}'
    $end = '" -f "Job_Name"'

    ForEach ($dt in $dates)
    {         
        $ft  += " {$num,10}"     
        $dtt += ",""$dt"""
        $num ++
    }

    "$($beg) $($ft) $($end)$($dtt)"
}
    
display $dates
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27"  
#>
```

You are passing in an array, so the response should be handled as an array.

```
Clear-Host
$dates | 
ForEach-Object {$PSItem}
2022-07-29
2022-07-28
2022-07-27

Clear-Host
$dates | 
ForEach{display -dates $PSitem}
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-28"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-27"
#>
```

Then you deal with those output lines as needed.

***Yet, ditto to what '@iRon' said.***

As of right now, your post is only sent to the console, and if you are needing to use the data elsewhere in the script, then you need to capture it and use it that way.

You can output to the screen and capture in a variable for use as needed, using PowerShell variable squeezing.

```
Clear-Host
($DisplayRecords = $dates | 
ForEach{display -dates $PSitem})
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-28"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-27"
#>

Clear-Host
$DisplayRecords
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-28"
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-27"
#>
```

Then you can cheery pick whichever you wanted:

```
Clear-Host
$DisplayRecords[0]
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29"
#>

Clear-Host
$DisplayRecords[1]
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-28"
#>

Clear-Host
$DisplayRecords[2]
# Results
<#
"{0,-25}  {1,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-27"
#>
```

***Update - followup to my comment below:***

```
Clear-Host
$dates = ("2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27")

function display ($dates)
{

    $end = 'Job_Name '

    ForEach ($dt in $dates)
    { $dtt += $dt }

    $end + $dtt
}
    
display $dates
# Results
<#
Job_Name 2022-07-292022-07-282022-07-27 
#>
```

Comment: currently i am getting follwing
PS C:\anil\scripts> .\display_dates.ps1
"{0,-25}  {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} " -f "Job_Name","2022-07-29","2022-07-28","2022-07-27"

But expectation is as shwn below
PS C:\anil\scripts> .\display_dates.ps1
job_name 2022-07-29 2022-07-28 2022-07-27

Comment: ***'@raji'***, again, my first response to you is using the code you posted, unchanged showing what you are talking to now, vs what you showed originally. Again, the dates are an array and must be treated that way, as my later code snippet shows. If you are saying all you'd want is what you show in your comment, then why is your code providing the: ***"$($beg) $($ft) $($end)$($dtt)"***, and what are you passing an array, vs a simple string?  ***$dates = ("2022-07-29 2022-07-28 2022-07-27")***, as well as all the other formatting you are showing.

Comment: i have added my main script which is cumbersome to adjust dates value if value for $days changes from 14 to any other value. I would like adjusting dates should be automatic . To achieve above i have created small script which is in topmost portion of thread, but that is not helping.